# Use of std::map<Obj*, int> in objects of TThread results in Access Violations

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdmap, tthread

I'm trying to parallelize a simulation model using TThreads. The model objects each include amongst other things a `std::map<obj*, int>`. The model runs fine as long only one thread is running. If a second thread starts, I get an access violation in the map of the model of the first thread.

To test if the map is really the problem, I replaced it with a `std::vector<pair<obj*, int> >`. This works fine, but is much slower since I have to iterate through the entire Vector every time I try to find a specific `obj*`.

I know there is no possibility to reserve memory for a map, therefore I don't know how to work with the map without access violations.

Comment: Do you *share* the map between the threads? Do you have any kind of protection against simultaneous access of the map (e.g. a mutex or a lock of some kind)?

Comment: No the map is not shared. Each thread has its own map.

Comment: are the objects *pointed to* by these unshared maps shared amongst the threads?

Comment: No, no memory is shared between the threads. All threads have a own model which runs completely alone. The objects in the maps are also part of the model.

Comment: Then you have to try and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Otherwise this question is impossible to answer, all we can give you are wiled (and mostly wrong) guesses. If you haven't done it yet, then please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (and if you have read it, then please read it again).

Comment: All right then. I will try to find an Example. I just thought maybe I missed something obvious.